# Nuget secondary file depends on current project build

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, expression-trees

I've written a library of expression-tree-related test objects (for the types in `System.Linq.Expressions`), which I use in tests for [ExpressionTreeToString](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString).

The library is in two .NET Standard class library projects within the solution:

1. [`ExpressionTreeTestObjects`](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString/tree/master/ExpressionTreeTestObjects) -- expressions generated [via the C# compiler](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString/tree/master/ExpressionTreeTestObjects/CSCompiler) and by [calling the expression tree factory methods](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString/tree/master/ExpressionTreeTestObjects/FactoryMethods)
2. [`ExpressionTreeTestObjects.VB`](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString/tree/master/ExpressionTreeTestObjects.VB) -- expressions generated by the VB.NET compiler

`ExpressionTreeTestObjects` also exposes the main entry point for getting the list of objects (via reflection over the assemblies in the current domain).

I want to publish both DLLs as a single NuGet package.

**Where should I put the NuGet package information?**

The obvious choice (to my mind) is in `ExpressionTreeTestObjects`. But how can there be a reference there to `ExpressionTreeTestObjects.VB`, when `ExpressionTreeTestObjects.VB` also depends on `ExpressionTreeTestObjects`?  Isn't this a cyclical build dependency?

---

I suppose an alternative would be to separate code which generates the expression tree objects, from the main entry point code; and put the entry code in a third project (`ExpressionTreeTestObjects.Loader`) which would reference both original projects. The package information would then go on that third project.

But adding a separate project feels like it should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've included the package information in the `ExpressionTreeTestObjects.VB` project, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString/blob/master/TestObjects.VB/TestObjects.VB.vbproj).